# Unable to upload odg file

Tags: 2007, document-library, sharepoint-library

What do I need to do to be able to upload a Libre Office Draw file (`.odg` extension) to a SharePoint document library without changing the extension?

It will currently accept the file, but it converts it into a `.zip` file. When I revert the extension back to `.odg` it will work with Libre Office Draw. However this prevents an issue when I am trying to get others to contribute to the document.

Comment: This isn't standard behavior. Is there anything custom going on with this library? Any special event receivers or anything?

Comment: @PirateEric No. There shouldn't be anything custom going on. Are you able to upload files with the `.odg` extension into your document libraries?

Comment: I mean that uploading a file under one extension and it storing as a zip file isn't standard. ODG files are not a blocked file type.

Comment: @PirateEric Thank you for that suggestion. I will verify that this is not the case.